# Decidability of first order theory of subclasses of posets

Tags: reference-request, posets, decidability

Is the first order theory of finite posets known to be undecidable?
Does anyone know a survey about such results?

Comment: I don’t know about a survey, but it’s certainly undecidable: for example, one can represent an undirected graph $(V,E)$ by the poset $V\mathbin{\dot\cup} E$ where each edge $e\in E$ is below its two endpoints.